# Flatlist rendering empty space

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

i'm new to react native and trying to use flatlist inside another component that's been rendered by another flatlist.

My concern is in the nested flatlist used like this:

**Card component**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { View, Image, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { QueryContext } from "../context/QueryContext"

function Card(props) {

    const [query, setQuery] = useContext(QueryContext)
    const { genres_list } = query

    const { posterURLs, originalTitle, genres } = props

    const listData = []

    genres.forEach(genre => {
        listData.push({ key: genres_list[genre] })
    })

    const renderItem = (item) => {

        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.item}>
                    {item.index}
                    {item.key}
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
                style={styles.images}
                source={{ uri: posterURLs["original"] }} />

            <Text style={styles.title}>{originalTitle}</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={listData}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item)=> item.key}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    images: {
        width: 400,
        height: 500
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,    
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 30
    },
    item: {
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: "red",
        
    },
})
```

I have to prepare the data for the flatlist since is inside an object that comes from the context. Weirdly enough i can see the index from `item.index` but not the `item.key` which makes me think is some styling issue but as much change i make i'm unable to see it

The card component is rendered by another flatlist and i don't know if that matters or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was showing because the data `item.key` values were actually stored in `item.item.key`